# C++ Access to vector from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, segmentation-fault, flags

In my program I've some threads running. Each thread gets a pointer to some object (in my program - vector). And each thread modifies the vector.

And sometimes my program fails with a segm-fault. I thought it occurred because thread A begins doing something with the vector while thread B hasn't finished operating with it? Can it be true?

How am I supposed to fix it? Thread synchronization? Or maybe make a flag `VectorIsInUse` and set this flag to true while operating with it?

Comment: You most likely need to guard the write operations with mutexes. Note that even if you lock write operations, iterators and references might get invalidated, so there is no totally safe solution. You're better off not performing modifying operations from more than one thread.

Comment: Hi, a segmentation fault is usually caused by accessing memory that is not reserved by your process. Could it be that you are using something as a pointer that actually isn't a pointer? Otherwise, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099513/threadsafe-vector-class-for-c

Comment: @juanchopanza - not just the write operations, **all** operations. **Every access** to shared data must be protected.

Comment: @PeteBecker agreed, and some accesses (e.g. references to elements of the container or iterators) you cannot really protect anyway...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`vector`, like all STL containers, is not thread-safe. You have to explicitly manage the synchronization yourself. A [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) or [`boost::mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) could be use to synchronize access to the `vector`.

Do not use a flag as this is not thread-safe:

- Thread A checks value of `isInUse` flag and it is `false`
- Thread A is suspended
- Thread B checks value of `isInUse` flag and it is `false`
- Thread B sets `isInUse` to `true`
- Thread B is suspended
- Thread A is resumed
- Thread A still thinks `isInUse` is `false` and sets it `true`
- Thread A and Thread B now both have access to the `vector`

Note that each thread will have to lock the `vector` for the entire time it needs to use it. This includes modifying the `vector` and using the `vector`'s iterators as iterators can become invalidated if the element they refer to is `erase()` or the `vector` undergoes an internal reallocation. For example **do not**:

```
mtx.lock();
std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = the_vector.begin();
mtx.unlock();

// 'i' can become invalid if the `vector` is modified.
```

Comment: Beware though that iterators and references may get invalidated, and you cannot protect against that with mutexes.

Comment: @juanchopanza, yep. Was still updating.

Comment: Gladly. I completely misread your answer. I saw the code sample and I was like "WHAAA EPIC FAIL!". Then I was like "Oh, wait.".

Comment: In any case, having to explicitly remember to lock the mutex before using the vector is quite unsafe, as nothing prevents accidental mis-use, and nothing prevents the iterators from leaking out. A `concurrent_vector` is much safer.

Comment: @DeadMG, is `concurrent_vector` Microsoft only?

Comment: There's also one in TBB, which is basically the same principle.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a container that is safe to use from many threads, you need to use a container that is explicitly designed for the purpose. The interface of the Standard containers is not designed for concurrent mutation or any kind of concurrency, and you cannot just throw a lock at the problem.

You need something like TBB or PPL which has `concurrent_vector` in it.

Answer (score 1):

That's why pretty much every class library that offers threads also has synchronization primitives such as mutexes/locks. You need to setup one of these, and aquire/release the lock around every operation on the shared item (read AND write operations, since you need to prevent reads from occuring during a write too, not just preventing multiple writes happening concurrently).