# Accessing vector over multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

How can I protect the vector v from crashing? And another question, why is not it already crashed, shouldn't it?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> v;

void a()
{
    while (true)
    {
        v.push_back(1);
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

void b()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!v.empty())
        {
            v.erase(v.begin());
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

void c()
{
    while (true)
    {
        v.push_back(1);

        Sleep(100);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread(&a).detach();
    thread(&b).detach();
    thread(&c).detach();

    while (true)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            v[i]++;
        }


        cout << v.size() << endl;


        if (!v.empty())
            v.erase(v.begin());

        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: A [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260946/c-access-to-vector-from-multiple-threads

Comment: Just to add to what others said, if you are only reading contents of a vector from multiple threads, it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access one vector from multiple thread, you need to add std::mutex, idiomatic way is to implement RAII, see below demo code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class raii_vector
{
public:
  raii_vector() {  }
  void Add() 
  { 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
    v_.push_back(1);
  }

  void Remove() 
  { 
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_);
    if (!v_.empty())
    {
        v_.erase(v_.begin());
    }
  }

private:
  std::mutex       m_;
  std::vector<int> v_;
};

raii_vector rv;

void a()
{
  while (true)
  {
    rv.Add();
    std::cout << "adding " << std::endl;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 100 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
  }
}

void b()
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::cout << "removing " << std::endl;
    rv.Remove();
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura( 100 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::thread t1(a);
  std::thread t2(b);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to use data structures such as vectors from multiple threads, I've found the [Intel Threading Building Blocks library](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) to be really useful.